# How to transform an actor-year dataset into a country-year dataset in R

Tags: r, dataframe, transformation

I am working on the following actor-year dataset, where the information on countries is given by a variable where each country is separated by a comma.

```
dt_initial <- data.frame(actor=c("Actor1","Actor1", "Actor2","Actor3"),year=c(2017,2018,2019,2020),
              country=c("Country1", "Country1", "Country1, Country2", "Country1, Country2, Country3"),
              amount=c(10,20,70,90))

> dt_initial
   actor year                      country amount
1 Actor1 2017                     Country1     10
2 Actor1 2018                     Country1     20
3 Actor2 2019           Country1, Country2     70
4 Actor3 2020 Country1, Country2, Country3     90
```

I would like to transform this dataset into a country-year dataset, in which I would have a row for each country. Additionnally, I would like the variable "amount" to be divided by the number of countries indicated in each row from the initial dataset.
My final dataset thus would be

```
dt_final <- data.frame(actor=c("Actor1", "Actor1","Actor2","Actor3", "Actor2", "Actor3", "Actor3"),year=c(2017, 2018, 2019,2020, 2019, 2020, 2020),
              country=c("Country1", "Country1", "Country1", "Country1",  "Country2", "Country2", "Country3"),
              amount=c(10, 20,35,30, 35, 30, 30))
> dt_final
   actor year  country amount
1 Actor1 2017 Country1     10
2 Actor1 2018 Country1     20
3 Actor2 2019 Country1     35
4 Actor3 2020 Country1     30
5 Actor2 2019 Country2     35
6 Actor3 2020 Country2     30
7 Actor3 2020 Country3     30
```

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can get data into different rows using `separate_rows`, `group_by` each `actor` and divide `amount` by number of rows in each group.

```
library(dplyr)

dt_initial %>%
   mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
   tidyr::separate_rows(country, sep = ", ") %>%
   group_by(row) %>%
   mutate(amount = amount/n()) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   select(-row)

#   actor   year country  amount
#  <fct>  <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>
#1 Actor1  2017 Country1     10
#2 Actor1  2018 Country1     20
#3 Actor2  2019 Country1     35
#4 Actor2  2019 Country2     35
#5 Actor3  2020 Country1     30
#6 Actor3  2020 Country2     30
#7 Actor3  2020 Country3     30
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help! I updated my question because it was not clear enough and with the code you provided, there were errors in computing "amounts". In the updated example, your code leads to the first two rows being equal to "5" and "10" for the variable "amount", while it should be "10" and "20", as shown in the updated example. If you have any suggestion it would be very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution

```
fn <- function(v) {
  u <- unlist(strsplit(as.character(v$country),", "))
  transform(do.call(rbind,c(make.row.names = FALSE, replicate(length(u),v,simplify = FALSE))),
            country = u, 
            amount = amount/length(u))
}
dt_out <- do.call(rbind,
                  c(make.row.names = FALSE, 
                    lapply(split(dt_initial,seq(nrow(dt_initial))), 
                           fn)))
```

such that

```
> dt_out
   actor year  country amount
1 Actor1 2017 Country1     10
2 Actor1 2018 Country1     20
3 Actor2 2019 Country1     35
4 Actor2 2019 Country2     35
5 Actor3 2020 Country1     30
6 Actor3 2020 Country2     30
7 Actor3 2020 Country3     30
```